# split screen render

Tags: rendering, animation

I have 8 different animations but i want to show then in split screens at video.

I can render the 8 animaton and bring them together by video editor. but is there a way to render 8 animation like split screen and get the final pictures or videos from blender?

there not different scenes just same scene with different movement speed, color etc.

Comment: You might be able to use translate and scale strips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's the setup for 4 images. For a 8 images setup it should be similar.
the 2 initial values are the render sizes in pixel (width and height).

[image]

Comment: Please explain the contents. New users might see this and not understand how to set the render layers to have different content from different cameras.

Comment: perfect answer! thanks!

Comment: If so, please consider to accept the answer @mavigozludev How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour